# Joomla XML form fields in content

Tags: xml, content

Joomla includes many built-in filds that can be used in the XML manifest file ([Available fields in Joomla XML manifest](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/available-fields-in-joomla-xml-manifest/4115#4115)), but is it possible to use them to build forms for the visitors, in a module or maybe in an article?

For instance, can I add a color picker to a front-end form?

```
<field name="backgroundcolor" type="color" default="#eee" label="Color selector field" description="TPL_BEEZ3_FIELD_HEADER_BACKGROUND_COLOR_DESC" />
```

*(this is from the xml file, but I would like to implement something similar in an article)*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, with Joomla's [JForm](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JForm.html), you can use them virtually anywhere - here's a [tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/getting-started-with-jform/) that might help, and an example to [Custom field](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type#Location_of_files) in a content plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="params" >
         <fieldset name="params" >
            <field
               name="content_myfield"
                type="text"
                label="PLG_CONTENT_GDP_MYFIELD"
                />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

The full example for this code is at [How to save Custom Fields in Core components](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components/2397#2397).